# How to remove space between distinct chars in a string using sed?

Tags: regex, string, sed

I want to remove the space between two distinct chars separated by space.

For example

In String "hello world doddy", I want the space between hello & world be removed (but preserve the space between world and doddy, since d d pattern needs to be preserved).

I tried:

```
$ echo "hello world doddy" | sed 's/\(.\) \([^\1]\)/\1\2/g'
```

But ended  up with

helloworlddoddy

Comment: Backreferences don’t expand in square brackets.  This is much more easily solved in Perl where you can have lookaheads etc as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prep the string by first doubling any space that is between two identical characters. The intervening space shifts from being between two identical characters to between one of the characters and a space, so all spaces can be checked the same way.

```
echo "hello world doddy" | sed -e 's/\(.\) \1/\1  \1/g' -e 's/\(.\) \(.\)/\1\2/g'
```

Comment: yes, this is very cool!  I ended up using @tripleee 's suggestion of using sentinel values - but this is cool.  thanks!

Comment: @potong With the extensions in GNU sed, it could be shortened as you suggest. I'll leave the more general form in the answer, but it's a nice tip for GNU sed users.

Comment: Perhaps `s/\([^ ]\) /\1/g` would be suffice?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a backref inside a character class.

I would approach this by using a sentinel for those cases where the space should be preserved, like so:

```
echo "hello world doddy" |
sed 's/\([^ ]\) \1/\1<<>>\1/g;s/\([^ ]\) \([^ ]\)/\1\2/g;s/<<>>/ /g'
```

Edit: changed `.` to `[^ ]` to avoid manging double spaces, just to be more precise.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You beat me to it. I'll vote you up when I get more votes. I'd replace `.` with `[^ ]` to make sure the bracketing characters aren't spaces.